# Multiplication between two table that does not have common key

Tags: sql, impala

So I wrote a impala query that calculate the max(price) by

```
SELECT Max(price) 
FROM 
(select close AS price from tableA) UNION 
(select strike AS price from tableB) AS T1
```

and so a sample output will be

```
Max(price)
200
```

Now I have another table with dates and number and I want to multiply 200 by the number associated with 1-16-15, so the desired output is

```
Date     num
1-16-15  40
1-17-15  30
```

40*200 = 8000

Answer (score 1):

You can put both subqueries in the `FROM` clause and then multiply:

```
SELECT Max(cs.price) * n.num
FROM ((select close AS price from tableA)
      UNION ALL
      (select strike AS price from tableB)
     ) cs CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT num
      FROM anothertable
      WHERE date = '2015-01-16'
     ) n;
```

Comment: Just tried it in impala, and returns an error saying that database does not exist:cs

Comment: @JamesXiang . . . Fix the table references so they refer to the right database.  This answer uses exactly the same table references as in your question.